# get row and column name value when I click in a gridview cell?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a gridview as shown here

[image]

As you can see, it is a gridview which shows a report where section are rows and options are columns. I would like to know if there is any possibility to get the row index and column (index or headertext) when I click on any cell. (i.e. If I click on the value "2" I want to get SECTION1 as row and OPTION1 as column) because I want to show a modalpopup extender from Ajax Controltoolkit to show the details of each one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you will get the value in datagridview_cellenter

```
Dim CurrentRow,CurrentCol as Integer
Dim CurrentCellName as String

Private Sub dgv_CellEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDataSiswa.CellEnter
    CurrentRow = e.RowIndex
    CurrentCol = e.ColumnIndex
    CurrentCellName = dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
End Sub
```

And there's no RowName coz it is numeric and depends on sort order .. you can make the SECTION one as field table and you can get the the value in cellenter_event